# How to pipe text into an embedded python interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter

I'm writing a python program that exposes a python API via a Python interpreter using `code.interact()`.

This works fine, but then sometimes I want to write API commands into the interpreter from the program.
For example, when the user wants to replay all his previous API commands.

I want to do something like:

In a threading.Thread instance have:

```
class MyConsole(threading.Thread):

    def run():
      shell = code.interact(local=locals())
```

In the main thread:

```
my_console = MyConsole()
my_console.start()

# Send a command to the 'input()' of the shell.
sys.stdin.write("print('Hello World')")
```

Ok the above line won't work, but what will?